# How to call a "hidden" method of some WPF User Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

It seems strange but I cast some custom WPF User Controls to WPF UserControl and I have to call some method which have all of them. Is it possible? How to do it?

```
foreach (var kid in ((MainWindow)App.Current.Windows[0]).MainCanvas.Children)
{
string kidType = kid.GetType().FullName;
if (kidType.EndsWith("MyUserControl"))
{
    UserControl myUserControl = (UserControl)kid;

    myUserControl.Hide() // <- this method I want to call bu it is "hidden" because of teh casting which doesn't provide access to it.
```

Note: The method `Hide()` is public.

**SOLUTION:**

Hi all!

Thanks for your input! Finally I got the solution.

```
foreach (var kid in ((MainWindow)App.Current.Windows[0]).MainCanvas.Children)
{
  string kidType = kid.GetType().FullName;
  if (kidType.EndsWith("UControl"))
  {
     Type t = kid.GetType();
     object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
     t.InvokeMember("Hide", BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, new object[] { });

      // And here there is a 1000% better solution of @Erno
      // dynamic myUserControl = kid;
      // myUserControl.Hide();
   }
}
```

where is

```
public void Hide()
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dynamic` might be useful to prevent writing reflection code  ([See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx)):

```
foreach (var kid in ((MainWindow)App.Current.Windows[0]).MainCanvas.Children) {
    string kidType = kid.GetType().FullName;
    if (kidType.EndsWith("MyUserControl"))
    {
        dynamic myUserControl = kid;
        myUserControl.Hide();  
    } 
}
```

Make sure you add some exception handling just in case you encounter a type that fits the name but doesn't implement Hide.

If you are worried about that you could implement an interface on all the UserControls and try-cast to that interface instead.

Comment: You're welcome. Please note that I'd prefer the solution to implement an interface over this one. I consider this `dynamic` solution only when I would have to use reflection because I have no access to the UserControls.

Answer (score 3):

Make all of your user controls implement an interface

```
public interface ICanHide
{
    void Hide();
}
```

then do this

```
foreach (var kid in ((MainWindow)App.Current.Windows[0]).MainCanvas.Children)  
{
   var tmp = kid as ICanHide;
   if (tmp != null)
   {
      tmp.Hide();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You solution is also possible. But In my case I don't have access to re-implement WPF User Controls to have public partial class UControl : UserControl, ICanHide

Comment: could you not create an additional partial class that implements the interface ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do an extra cast:

```
foreach (var kid in ((MainWindow)App.Current.Windows[0]).MainCanvas.Children)
{
    string kidType = kid.GetType().FullName;
    if (kidType.EndsWith("MyUserControl"))
    {
         UserControl myUserControl = (UserControl)kid;

         if (myUserControl is MyUserControlClass)
         {
             (myUserControl as MyUserControlClass).Hide();
         }
    }
}
```

Where MyUserControlClass is the class with the hide method. If you have a collection of controls with the same Hide method which are not derived by a base class which has Hide, you can either:

1. Create a cast for every control class
2. Create your own controls, and let them inherit from an interface with the method Hide.

Edit:

or with reflection:

```
typeof(ctrlobject.GetType()).GetMethod("Hide").Invoke(ctrlobject, new object[] { });
```

Comment: Thanks! But I cannot do like you suggests because no access to MyUserControlClass. I load all WPF User controls on fly. So it could be any type of User Control. But all of them have the same method - Hide()

Comment: Then, for each type, you have to check if the control is of that type and cast it to that type. There aren't that many usercontrols with hide, are there?

Comment: I create WPF UserControls using Reflection. So I dain't have any references to the classes...

Comment: Do it like this: typeof(ctrlobject).GetMethod("Hide").Invoke(ctrlobject, new object[] { });

Comment: forgot the .GetType() after the first ctrlobject, look in the answer

Comment: It's better to use `as` and `!=null`, then `is` and `as`.

Comment: there's no need to use the 'as' operator after the is it's safe to simply cast. otherwise use the as operator before the if an check for null instead

Answer (score 0):

```
MyUserControl muc = kid as MyUserControl;
if (muc != null)
    muc.Hide();
```

Comment: @Dmitry: If `Hide()` is a member of `MyUserControl`, then read UserControl as MyUserControl. I've updated my answer. It should work